# pygame e.button not working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to capture the position of the mouse when it is first clicked.

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError:'Event' object has no attribute 'button'
```

**Question:** What does this mean and how do I fix it?

**My code:**

```
running=True
while running:
    for e in event.get():
        print(e)
        if e.type==QUIT:
            running=False
        if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pic=screen.copy()
        if e.button==1:
            smx,smy= e.pos
```

Comment: this error means `e` an object of type `Event` does not have the property of `button`, therefore since i do not know pygame from memory, check the documentation, as it should tell you how to get that property from type `Event` (if even possible at all).

Comment: i looked it up (on my phone, sorry) and i did not see a button property for type `Event`... you are already doing the correct thing by checking the `e.type==` now just find the key code for `1`

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the built in `mouse` methods? https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just happens because the last two lines are not indented correctly. Only mouse events like `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` have a `button` attribute, so you'll get that error if for example a `KEYDOWN` event (or any other event type) gets added to the event queue. Try this version:

```
running=True
while running:
    for e in event.get():
        print(e)
        if e.type==QUIT:
            running=False
        if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pic=screen.copy()
            if e.button==1:
                smx,smy= e.pos
```